# Selenium C# how to get Element

Tags: selenium

```
  <a href="javascript:;" class="btn green request-action-btn" data-request-status="Approved" data-id="212"> Approve </a>
```

How can I get this element in selenium C#. I tried by:href ,Xpath, ID, class name, text name but I couldn't get this element

Comment: which value are you looking for ?

Comment: I just need get this button and click on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can click by Link text

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Approve")).Click();
```

or by CSS Selector

```
.btn.green.request-action-btn
```

Answer (score 1):

To identify the element you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a.btn.green.request-action-btn[data-request-status='Approved']"))
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='btn green request-action-btn' and @data-request-status='Approved']"))
  ```
- *XPath* using contains():

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='btn green request-action-btn'][contains(.,'Approve')]"))
  ```
- *XPath* using normalize-space():

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='btn green request-action-btn'][normalize-space()='Approve']"))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It can be found by using tagName as below:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> anchrTags= driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
IWebElement roWebElement = anchrTags.Where(x => x.Text == "Approve").FirstOrDefault();
```

Otherwise if the anchor tag exists in the frames, it will not found. try switching to that frame:

```
IWebElement iframe = driver.FindElements(By.Id("iframeId"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);
IWebElement roWebElement = anchrTags.Where(x => x.Text == "Approve").FirstOrDefault();
```